# Unable to forward message sent as attachment from public folder

Tags: outlook, exchange-2016, outlook-2016

We run an on-site Exchange server and use a mixture of Outlook 2016, Office 365 Outlook and OWA to access the e-mail. We recently upgraded the Exchange server from Exchange 2010 to Exchange 2016. We used https://supertekboy.com/2016/03/09/exchange-2016-public-folder-migration-made-easy/ and https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/Exchange/collaboration/public-folders/batch-migration-from-previous-versions?view=exchserver-2016 to perform the public folder migration.

We have a series of public folders the we use as a "store and forward" mechanism for some of our e-mails. The forwarded e-mails are sent as attachments. After migrating to Exchange 2016 we are unable to reply to or forward the attached e-mails. My first thought was that this is an Exchange 2016 issue, but discovered that the forward/reply function works in OWA. This makes me think it may be an Outlook issue with Exchange 2016 public folders.

The public folder permissions are currently set to default to owner.

I have searched for forwarding and permissions issues on both the Exchange and Outlook side to no avail.

I am open to any suggestions.

Thanks,
Eric.

**Edit 1:** I can send an e-mail with an e-mail attachment from my inbox (not from a public folder) and the attachment can be forwarded as normal.

Comment: By "we are unable to reply to or forward the attached e-mails", do you mean nothing occurs when you click Reply or Forward button? Is there any error messages? Does this problem occurs to both Outlook 2016 and Outlook for Office 365?

Comment: Yuki Sun, Sorry my explanation wasn't clear. The Reply, Reply All and Forward buttons do not appear in the menu bar in Outlook 2016 and Outlook 365. The buttons are there for OWA.